# How do I programmatically add field collections instances to a form?

Tags: entities

I have a form with field collections; on form validation I need to add instances of that field collection type. For example, field collection user_data has fields first_name, Last_name; when someone submits the form, I want to add as many fist_name and last_names as I want, programmatically. The field collection user_data is set as unlimited.

I was thinking to something like the following.

```
// Create new field collection item of type user_data
// Set first_name, last_name
// Append field collection item to $form some how
```

I'm just not sure how to do this, or even if it's possible.

Comment: a form (a Form API form) is not a drupal Field API widget. A `field collection` is a Field used in an `Entity`, not a simple HTML form.

Comment: I'm using Entityforms with an embedded field collections field.